# Cummulative addition in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy

I am trying to cummatively add a value to the previous value and each time, store the value in an array.

This code is just part of a larger project. For simplicity i am going to define my variables as follows:

```
ele_ini = [12]
smb = [2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]

val = ele_ini
for i in range(len(smb)):
     val += smb[i]
     print(val)
     elevation_smb.append(val)
```

**Problem**

Each time, the previous value stored in `elevation_smb` is replaced by the current value such that the result i obtain is:

```
elevation_smb = [22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22]
```

The result i am expecting however is

```
elevation_smb = [14, 19, 26, 34, 43, 53]
```

**NOTE**:
`ele_ini` is a vector with n elements. I am only using 1 element just for simplicity.

Comment: `np.cumsum(smb) + 12`?

Comment: @coldspeed - Check last NOTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems vector in your case is using pointers. That's why it is not creating new values. Try adding `copy()` which copies the value.

```
elevation_smb.append(val.copy())
```

Answer (score 4):

Don use loops, because slow. Better is fast vectorized solution below.

I think need [`numpy.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and add vector `ele_ini` for `2d numpy array`:

```
ele_ini = [12, 10, 1, 0]
smb = [2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]

elevation_smb  = np.cumsum(np.array(smb)) + np.array(ele_ini)[:, None]
print (elevation_smb)
[[14 19 26 34 43 53]
 [12 17 24 32 41 51]
 [ 3  8 15 23 32 42]
 [ 2  7 14 22 31 41]]
```

Comment: @Rahul K P - Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Do with `reduce`,

```
In [6]: reduce(lambda c, x: c + [c[-1] + x], smb, ele_ini)
Out[6]: [12, 14, 19, 26, 34, 43, 53]
```